# how to find the non-causal vectors from a difference equation in matlab?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, signals, signal-processing, matlab-deployment

I am trying to find the causality from a given difference equation and here's what I have already done.

```
y[n] = x[n]-x[n-4]
```

I know that I can find the causality by the *necessary condition* of impulse response h[n]=0,n<0.
I already know how to find the response using filter and filtic operations in Matlab to any input so, one way would be to make an input only equal to '1' at n=0 and '0' everywhere else at the defined interval and finding the response.

My question is about making the numerator and denominator vectors in filter operation. This particular case has `num = [1 0 0 0 -1]` and `den = 1` and I know how to make those with [value of n progressing downwards correspond to vector entries] but what will be the value of these vectors in a non-causal system for example:

```
y[n]=x[n]+x[n+1]
```

I am still learning Matlab so I will appreciate any help.

Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [image] domain the recurrence `y[n] = x[n] + x[n+1]` becomes:

[image]

In MATLAB you can do

```
>> num = [1 1];
>> den = [0 1];
>> sys = filt([1 1], [0 1]) % Alternatively: sys = tf([1 1], [0 1], -1, 'variable', 'z^-1')

sys =

  1 + z^-1
  --------
    z^-1

Sample time: unspecified
Discrete-time transfer function.
```

Anyway when you try to use [`stepplot()`](https://mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/stepplot.html) or [`impz()`](https://mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/impz.html) you get the following errors:

```
>> stepplot(sys)
Error using DynamicSystem/stepplot (line 107)
Cannot simulate the time response of improper (non-causal) models.

>> impz([1 1], [0 1])
Error using filter
First denominator filter coefficient must be non-zero.
```

the same happens when you try to use [`zplane()`](https://mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/zplane.html):

```
>> zplane([1 1], [0 1])
Error using tf2zp (line 41)
Denominator must have non-zero leading coefficient.
```

And that's because **non-causal** filters are **not physically realizable**, therefore MATLAB can't simulate such responses or identify transfer function's zeros and poles neither.

Comment: Yes that's pretty much what I concluded as well.
Thanks for confirming my doubts:)

Answer (score 1):

There is possibility that you are interpreting the use of `num` and `den` incorrectly.

Primarily, `num/den` is used for representing **transfer function** of a given equation.
Transfer function is generally used to find if the system/eqn is stable/feasible and find output for any input.

A transfer function(H(s)) is,

`H(s)=( Y(s)/X(s) )`

and Y(s) and X(s) are the laplace transform of y(t) and x(t).
For sampled signal, rules are same for x[n].

> For original question, take **laplace transform** on either side will give-

`y[n] = x[n]-x[n-4]
Y(s)=X(s)-(s^4)*X(s)
or, Y(s)/X(s)= (1-(s^4))`

so, `num=[-1 0 0 0 1] and den=1`

> For the second equation,

`y[n]=x[n]+x[n+1]
Y(s)=X(s)-X(s)/s
or, Y(s)/X(s)= (1-1/s)=(s-1)/s`

so, `num=[1 -1] and den=[1 0]`

> And the transfer fn will be tf(num/den)

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I went into control systems a bit deep, because you used `non-casual` system word in your question.  If you dont know about laplace transform, just remember matlabs laplace and inverse laplace functions.

Comment: This is a discrete time system (OP says *"difference equation"*). I believe you have to use Z-transform, not Laplace.

Comment: I have studied Laplace and inverse Laplace for differential equations but not for difference equations. I am currently studying Z-transform for difference equations.

The _num_ and _den_ I found were by reading the filter command doc and it gave the correct output to my custom input which I verified myself.
So, I do not think these new vectors will represent the same system.

There has to be another way to plot non-causal systems.Substitution and shifting didn't work as the first co-efficient of _den_ has to be non-zero.
Thanks

Comment: @Marco you are correct. but laplace and z transform idea is same. you will get the same transfer equations as given in the answer. 
@Zero_Cool these `num and den` **will** represent the same systems, you just need to know how to use the **transfer equation**

Comment: @PranavTotala I do believe that this system will represent the same system but if I put these values of _num_ and _den_ in my ""filter" function, it will not behave the same as it takes z-transform values (both of these transforms give different values btw) So, is there any other function that can help me take impulse response from the transfer function then?
My main goal is to check causality.
Thanks

Comment: @PranavTotala Surely there's a duality between Z-transform and Laplace transorm. But you won't get the same transfer functions, in fact in the first case you'll have `1 - z^-4`, so `num = [1 0 0 0 -1]`, not `num = [-1 0 0 0 1]`.